# How to use “software-properties-gtk”?

Tags: python, 20.04, update-manager

On Ubuntu 20.04, Software and update (gui) doesn't work.

When I try running from terminal, I get:

```
# software-properties-gtk
ERROR:dbus.proxies:Introspect error on :1.136:/: dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-properties-gtk", line 100, in <module>
    app = SoftwarePropertiesGtk(datadir=options.data_dir, options=options, file=file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py", line 211, in __init__
    self.backend.Reload();
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 72, in __call__
    return self._proxy_method(*args, **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 141, in __call__
    return self._connection.call_blocking(self._named_service,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 652, in call_blocking
    reply_message = self.send_message_with_reply_and_block(
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name :1.136 was not provided by any .service files
```

How do I fix the issue?

Comment: You should run it as normal user. It will ask *sudo*er password when needed.

Comment: Yes, i use sudo  -s

Answer (score 1):

I made a lot of attempts, but the one that solved it was this

`sudo aptitude reinstall python3-six python3-certifi`

Source: https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/software-updates-fails-to-open/22736/4

Comment: This is the solution indeed. You may replace `aptitude` with `apt`

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall:( and everything works fine

But, it is possible that video2x caused the error
https://github.com/k4yt3x/video2x/wiki/Run-From-Source-Code